# What is "time lapse mode" in video recording?

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

What is "time lapse mode" in video recording? I read this term in Android documentation for class MediaRecorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time lapse photography is taking a picture at longer intervals than normal e.g. instead of taking 24 frames per second you take 1 frame per second and then play that back at normal speed.

Comment: Thank you!I see what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-lapse

Comment: Thank you! Wikipedia is really useful！